# Why won't my condenser turn on when I run my heat pump?

Tags: heating, furnace, central-heating, heat-pump

I have a York Affinity condenser. When I run my heat pump, I expect it to turn on somewhere in the cycle but it doesn't. It generally does this once a year. The usual fix is to cycle the power of the ac and the furnace. This year, it didn't fix it and I have to use propane to heat the house.

Any ideas?

Comment: How cold is it outside when this happens?

Comment: Have you tried whacking it with a hammer/wrench?

Comment: Happens at 30 degrees, up to 60 degrees, no heat. Whacked it. No joy.

Comment: In extreme cold, e.g. 30 degrees, the heat pump loses all it's efficiency, so you should be on emergency heat (electric) or some other alternative at that point. The fact that it could be fixed with a power cycle indicates a possible issue with the controller.

Comment: Does your heat pump have a crankcase heater? If not, that could be the problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crankcase_heater